# Function can search for value in df and return it

Tags: r

I need help ton find a solution to my probleme.

I'm working in Rmarkdown. So, i'm doing report and I encounter a problem in the display of a caption of a code.
In main code, I can only display the code, but what I really want is to display the code as well as its label.

I have a side dataframe, which contains the codes and their labels.

For exemple:

```
Here's my report : "UK"

What i want to show: "UK (United Kingdom)"

My data frame contains code and label is: 
CODE   LABEL
FR     France
UK     United Kingdom
```

Thanks you

Comment: The question is not well formulated. Your example does not include a data frame. I assume `df1` is supposed to be something like `df1 <- data.frame(label=c("UK"),name=c("United Kingdom"))` if so then you would just need to do `df1[df1$label=="UK","name"]` or similar

Comment: @Sam i Edit the post, tell me if it's well formulated